# How do I load jquery snippets before load the .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

After setting the .js file to ASYNC load the inlined snippets trigger the "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error.

Is there any way to load these snippets before .js loads? Or how else do I solve this?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var modals = ['#bookings', '#studios', '#mygallery', '#social', '#reviews', '#articles', '#contactme', '#credits', '#pagemap', '#tsandcs', '#events'];
        if (window.location.hash && ~modals.indexOf(window.location.hash)) {
            $(window.location.hash).modal();
        }
        $("#cul8a").modal('show');
        $(".modal:not(.noclose)").on("click", "a", function() {
            $(this).closest(".modal").modal("hide");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you telling the browser to load it asynchronously if you need it loaded before some other code?

Comment: I'd like to keep it in ASYNC mode for performance reasons.